# Get a list of characters that "belong" to the current culture

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, character-encoding, cultureinfo

I would like to create a string containing all characters that the current user can be expected to be able to enter on a keyboard. For a user in an English speaking culture, that would be the 26 upper case and 26 lower case letters, 10 decimal digits and 30+ symbols. Users from other countries would have some different characters.

I realise that there are ways for a user to enter characters that are not on his or her keyboard, but I can't assume that they know how to do that. I'm looking for a set of characters that it is reasonable for me to assume that anyone with the current culture should be able to enter. It's not the end of the world if the set is missing one or two special characters, but I would like it to be reasonable complete.

I can quickly get the US English character set either by hard coding it or using a function like this:

```
Function GetCharacterSet() As String
    Return Enumerable.Range(32, 95).Select(Function(i) Chr(i)).ToArray
End Function
```

I'm not sure how to do this reliably for other cultures. I can code the function like this:

```
Function GetCharacterSet() As String
    Dim chars As New List(Of Char) 
    For i As Integer = 0 To UInt16.MaxValue 
        Dim ch As Char = ChrW(i)
        If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) OrElse Char.IsPunctuation(ch) OrElse ch = " "c Then 
            chars.Add(ch)
        End If
    Next
    Return chars.ToArray 
End Function
```

But the resulting (very long) string contains characters that are valid in **any** culture. Is there a way to check if a character is a letter, digit or punctuation in the **current** culture only?

Comment: not sure exactly what your intention is here, but what do you do with words that are in the english dictionary that don't use all 'english' characters? words like `fiancé`?

Comment: @DLeh: I do not want to include characters that I can't rely on the user knowing how to enter on a keyboard. That means no accented characters in English (even though they may appear in dictionaries).

Comment: what if they copy the text from somewhere? are you going to disallow them from entering those characters anywhere? whats the goal there

Comment: @DLeh: I'm not trying to validate random text entered by the user, I am going to require the user to enter something and I don't want it to include characters that he doesn't know how to enter.

Comment: Your English example excludes the £ symbol on my UK English keyboard, as well as many other characters on the United Kingdon Extended or United States International keyboard.  There's no well-defined mapping from characters to cultures, so I think you're doomed to failure.

Comment: Dude, a lot of people don't know how to use the characters they _do_ have available to them ... ;)

Comment: why not just say that it's a required field and be done with it instead of `you must enter one of the characters '1234567890-=][poiuytrewqasdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./~!@#$%^&*)+}{POOOIUYTREWQASDFGBHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?'`

Comment: @joe: I'm guessing the UK £ symbol occupies the same place in the ASCII character set as the US $ symbol. In that case my first function might just happen to work for both en-US and en-UK (although I haven't checked). But I'm sure it wouldn't work for fr-FR. You may be right about me being doomed to failure though.

Comment: "I'm guessing the UK £ symbol occupies the same place in the ASCII character set" - no, you're guessing wrong.  The £ symbol isn't in the ASCII character set: it is in extended character sets such as CP1252 (0xA3).

Comment: OK @Joe I wasn't sure. My point was that my first function returns exactly the 95 characters I can enter on my US keyboard. It probably returns characters that do not appear on all keyboards and there are no doubt keys on non-US keyboards that do not appear on mine. That is the problem I am hoping (perhaps against hope) to solve.

Comment: @Blackwood - "perhaps against hope" is probably right.  Even in the US, someone using the en-US culture may have a US-International keyboard which allows additional characters, or may be a UK ex-pat who has sneaked in his UK keyboard with a £ symbol.  In Europe it's even more complex, especially for multilingual countries such as Belgium.  And that's before we even start considering non-latin characters.

Comment: @Joe: All true, although I'm assuming that the user knows how to use his keyboard to enter the characters used in the culture he has chosen for his PC. For example the UK ex-pat using his old keyboard in the US will either set his culture to en-UK or will learn how to enter a US $ symbol.

Comment: I started the bounty because I'm very interested in this question.I need to validate whether a string contains only characters of an specified culture. I would like to discover a managed or unmanaged way to retrieve, at least, all the alphabetical letters of an specific culture, however, I really would like also to retrieve all the complete charset of an specific culture.

Comment: So essentially this would boil down to getting the current keyboard layout and enumerating all characters that can be produced by it, I guess?

Comment: @Joey I'm not sure but I think there could be a big difference between "The charcters of a culture" and "The characters that a keyboard can produce", for example I'm spanish (from Spain) and my spanish keyboard can produce the dollar char "$" (Shit-key + D4) or also "&" (Shift-key + D6) but of course this does not remains to Spanish lang. this seems very hard or maybe impossible, but at least the alphabetical letters could get it in an automated way?, ignoring special characters.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Well, filtering out letters is trivial, though. But given the way this question is asked, it's either grabbing a list of alphabets for different languages somewhere, or kinda extrapolate from the keyboard layout. Of course, in my case this would kinda fail since even though I'm German I'm using US International as layout which can produce lots of letters that belong to other languages. Analysing the keyboard layout will have problems with dead keys, though, so it's a lot of trial and error, I guess.

Comment: @Joey With the loop that is published in the OP question seems we can get all the characters, well, I discovered that getting only the alphabet letters seems possible and very viable evaluating each char obtained with that loop, with `System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory` function, however, the problem I found is the same as the OP said, I can't filter the resulting list by an specific culture. I wll still checking the Globalization class for something useful.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: The fundamental problem is that characters don't belong to a culture per se. They're just characters. IMHO the closest thing that works here would actually be keyboard layouts because they can be reasonably expected to link languages and characters. Even Unicode doesn't have such lists that could be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this is a bit backwards, but was the best I could manage with the Keyboard Layout APIs, so far:

```
public class Api
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint idThread);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern short VkKeyScanEx(char ch, IntPtr dwhkl);
}

class Program
{
    static bool IsRepresentable(char c, IntPtr keyboardLayout)
    {
        var x = Api.VkKeyScanEx(c, keyboardLayout);
        return x != -1;
    }

    static IEnumerable<char> GetKeyboardLayoutCharacters(IntPtr keyboardLayout)
    {
        return
            Enumerable.Range(32, char.MaxValue - 32)
                .Select(n => (char)n)
                .Where(c => IsRepresentable(c, keyboardLayout));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var layout = Api.GetKeyboardLayout(Api.GetCurrentThreadId());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(GetKeyboardLayoutCharacters(layout)));
    }
}
```

This actually searches all of the BMP and asks whether each character can be represented by the given keyboard layout. Not ideal, but it returns the following:

**German:**

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
{|}~§°²³´µÄÖÜßäöüẞ€
```

**Polish:**

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
{|}~ÓóĄąĆćĘęŁłŃńŚśŹźŻż€
```

**US English:**

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

**US International ;-):**

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©«¬®°²³´µ¶¹»¼½¾¿ÁÄÅÆÇÉÍÐÑÓÖ×ØÚÜÞßáäåæçéíðñóö÷øúüþ‘’€
```

I'm fairly sure there must be a way of actually grabbing the characters a given keyboard layout can produce, because above list doesn't take into account dead keys (e.g. US International can actually produce `ÿ`, `õ`, or `ï` but they're not on the list because it's impossible to produce them using Shift, Ctrl, or Alt – you have to use dead keys). But as a first approximation this might be useful already. Furthermore, a few things are weird in there, not so much the inclusion of U+007F (which is <kbd>Del</kbd>), but rather U+F000 and U+F001. Additional filtering of the returned list may be necessary.

This method also assumes that a keyboard layout is active for the user that represents their language. However, this is probably most often the case if this is only about the current user's language.

**EDIT:**

Vb.Net Version

```
Private NotInheritable Class NativeMethods
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Shared Function VkKeyScanEx(ByVal ch As Char, ByVal dwhkl As IntPtr) As Short
    End Function
End Class

<Extension>
Public Function IsAlphabetic(ByVal sender As String,
                             ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Boolean

    If Not CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures).Contains(culture) Then
        Throw New CultureNotFoundException(paramName:="culture", message:="Culture not installed.")

    Else
        ' Keyboard Layout Handle (HKL)
        Dim hkl As IntPtr = InputLanguage.FromCulture(culture).Handle

        Dim charList As New List(Of Char)
        For index As UShort = 0US To (UShort.MaxValue - 1US)

            Dim c As Char = Convert.ToChar(index)

            ' The check for being a letter can always be removed if symbols or numbers should be allowed, too.
            If (NativeMethods.VkKeyScanEx(c, hkl) <> -1S) AndAlso Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) Then
                charList.Add(c)
            End If

        Next index

        For Each c As Char In sender
            If Not charList.Contains(c) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next

        Return True

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with the function. It returns me this charset for spanish `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzªºÇÑçñ` however the chars `ª` and `º` are special symbols, but the `Char.IsLetter()` function determines it is a letter, why?

Comment: It not works as expected at all, because if I pass an `á` char to `Char.IsLetter` function it determines it is a letter (and yes, it is) but I don't get that letter in the charlist that I obtain. maybe is because the dead key `´`? It can be possible with your code to retrieve these letters?: `áéíóú ÁÉÍÓÚ àèìòù ÀÈÌÒÙ äëïöü ÄËÏÖÜ` and the corresponding accented letters for other languages?

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Both [`ª`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00aa/index.htm) and [`º`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ba/index.htm) have Unicode category *Letter, other*, so they're letters as far as Unicode is concerned. And yes, as I mentioned, the method I wrote above only copes with characters that can be obtained without dead keys. I haven't managed to get `ToUnicodeEx` working yet. The other option would (I think) be, to query the layout for every possible keyboard state, including combining dead keys with every other one. Lots of problems lie that way, I fear.

Comment: I think some letters are missing. I tried the code in my computer with tr-TR keyboard and layout. For example, the output does not contains "İ" and "ı".

Comment: @Kemal: I get `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÆÇÖÜßæçéöüĞğİıŞş` (reduced to just letters) which includes both `İ` and `ı`. Windows says »Turkish Q« as keyboard layout. Note that the characters are sorted in Unicode order, *not* in the order they would appear in in a dictionary.

Comment: @Joey: I couldn't see in the console output (Console.WriteLine), but if I write output to a txt file then I can see those letters :) So, code works, thanks.

Comment: @Kemal: You may want to set your console to a TrueType font (e.g. Lucida Console or Consolas) in that case. If it's set to Raster fonts the console is limited to the OEM character set, no matter what the application running inside does.